# Cannot read property 'empId' of undefined

Tags: angular7

following is the response(Json) :

```
{
    "formId": 2,
    "empId": {
        "empEmail": "abc@gmail.com",
        "empName": "John",
        "empId": "1234",
        "role": 3
    },
    "skillClass": "UI",
    "fromDate": "2019-07-18T18:30:00.000+0000",
    "toDate": "2019-07-26T18:30:00.000+0000",
    "status": "open",
    "userComments": "ee3de3",
    "allocatedHours": 0,
    "comments": null
}
```

The TS. file is :

```
data = {};
this.data = reponse;
```

And the HTML:

```
 input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.empId.empId"  disabled name="empId" minlength="4" #empId="ngModel"  class="form-control" required
```

But I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'empId' of undefined

**How do I get rid of this error?**

Comment: Are you sure that this.data is in the same format as the response object? Try to do a console.log(this.data) and see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question seems a little incomplete, it looks like you have a typo in:

```
this.data = reponse;
```

Likely it should be:

```
this.data = response;
```